# AS3 Tiled Background With Different Tiles

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, background

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to make a tiled background. I've looked at a lot of other people talking about this but to me it seems like all the ones I've read are talking about just making a repeating background.

I want to be able to have different images/tiles to make my background.

This image:
http://ft.trillian.im/e246659bd210e2ec6d17acc076468f23fbc820d5/6hIXP37GTFJEfNukDmBkCFN6yh3lx.jpg
Shows what I'm thinking of. 1&2 are the same tiles like 3&4 and 5,6,7 are the same.

I'm pretty new, I'm not sure if I need to do a bitmap like I've seen on other questions or a sprite or movieclip or what.

What I do know is that I need it to be created dynamically and only be in the background. If the user were to click on it, it wouldn't recognize that it's being clicked it. (In other words it would think the user is touching the stage.) I also need to be able to interact with movie clips on top of the background. 
I also may want to layer other background images on top of the original background. I'm not sure about that, maybe I will just make a new tile for that type of stuff.

Is this the wrong way of going about it? Is it more practical to just to draw the whole background as one large image?

Part of the reason I thought to do it this way is so that I can make other parts of background that currently being displayed on the stage un-visible to save on processing. Or something to that effect maybe removing it completely and then re-adding it if it comes into view.

Any specific code to how you would even add just an image to the stage this way would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after is a tiling engine. You can write a naive implementation from scratch if you're up for it. The basic components are a tile map, a collection of sprites and an engine to put them both together.

Your tile map would be a two dimensional array of sprite IDs.

```
var tilemap:Array = [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Each number corresponds to a sprite ID that refers to a filename or a symbol linkage ID.

The engine parses through the tilemap, fetches the sprite and composes a larger background bitmap by placing the sprites side by side.

A good tutorial on this practice is available at http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/parsing-tiled-tmx-format-maps-in-your-own-game-engine/.